# Cassandra tombstone_thresholdの最小値

Tags: cassandra

Cassandraのtombstone_thresholdの最小値を教えて頂けないでしょうか。
マニュアル等を見ても判断できなく困っています。0.01までは実際に試して
有効と確認できました。
因みにCassandra3.0でコンパクションストラテジは、DTCSです。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

`tombstone_threshold` は Java の float なので、理論的には 2^-149 まで設定できます。

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/compaction/AbstractCompactionStrategy.java#L107

実際には、 `tombstone_threshold` は以下のメソッドの中で参照されている通り、SSTableのTombstoneの割合に関する統計情報の値と比較し、SSTable単独でのコンパクションを行うかを決定します。

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/compaction/AbstractCompactionStrategy.java#L368

Cassandraが実際にTombstonesを削除可能になるのは、テーブルに設定された gc_grace_seconds の時間を過ぎた後になります(デフォルトで10日間)。
上のコード内で取得している統計情報

```
sstable.getEstimatedDroppableTombstoneRatio(gcBefore);
```

は、SSTable内に、gc_grace_seconds を過ぎたTombstoneが何割あるかを計算します。

(ちなみに、DTCSはCassandra 3.0.8で非推奨となりました。TimeWindowCompactionStrategy (TWCS)への移行も検討してみてはいかがでしょうか。)

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataMaintain.html

Comment: yukimさん、いつもご回答ありがとうございます。理解できました。DTCSに関しては不明な点が多いです。また、過去データの削除時のTombstoneのpurgeに関して別途ケースとして質問する予定ですので、ご教示頂ければ幸いです。